# How to make a Block builder \drag and drop layout program?

Tags: c++, linux, gtk#, glade, gtkmm

Im new to GUI programming and i want to create a program that has modules and enables its user to connect these modules together by draging and dropping them then connecting them together visually in order to create a structure for simulation.

Example software already in market :
Proteus , EV3 lego software , matlab simulink

Im planning to use glade with gtkmm although all I found on the subject is the drag and drop tutorial which isnt that usefull

I really just need guide lines and where to start on learning how to make my project

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any GTK+ or gtkmm API that will help much, though I wish something suitably high-level existed. I have implemented something fairly similar, for designing database table diagrams:

http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2007/02/17/glom-relationships-overview/

and for designing print layouts for database records.
I used GooCanvas via goocanvasmm, but had to implement several classes to provide generic functionality such as drag-to-move, drag-corner-to-resize, snap-to-grid, snap-to-lines, etc. My code works but I'm not very proud of it:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/tree/glom/utility_widgets/canvas

Glade won't help you much with this. It's for laying out normal widgets, not for implementing specialized UIs such as this.

Comment: thank you for response . Your program represent an example of what I need to do I might just go and learn on goocanvas but I noticed some limitations and unstability with it as mentioned on your website . Do you know other gui enviorments i can use or do you advice me to go ahead with canvas ?

Comment: That's a very old blog post, from 2007. I just linked to it for the screenshot. I have since got it working very well. I can recommend Goocanvas even though it doesn't offer the higher-level user interaction that I'd like some library to offer.